# jQuery .toggle() элемент исчезает при щелчке

Tags: jquery, animate

Использую код для анимации по щелчку:

```
    $(".first_step").click(function(){
      $(".first_step").toggle(function(){
          $(this).animate({"right": "+=150px", "height": "show"}, "slow");
       },
       function(){
          $(this).animate({"right": "-=150px", "height": "show"}, "slow");
       });
    });
```

Как избавиться от "слайдап" исчезновения элемента .first_step при щелчке и почему оно происходит в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите у Вас две ошибки:

1. "height": "show" - такого нет в природе) (на мое скромное мнение)
2. метод toogle и так циклически переключает функции при нажатии ЛКМ, не нужно делать еще одно событие. То есть уберите click оставте только toogle.

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет вам fadeToggle вместо toggle ну и собственно надо height: show убрать я думаю

Comment: Метод fadeToggle используется для исчезновения / появления элементов. Мне нужно просто переключать вызов двух функций по щелчку.